# fastai-NameError: name 'TabularList' is not defined

Tags: python, fast-ai

I am new to pytorch and fastai. and I have been struggling to sovle few errors by googling. Now I am finally stuck. I am very frustrated. I did try fastai 2 years ago and eventually gave up, now I am trying it again and almost give up again. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much

here is the code:

```
import fastai
fastai.__version__
'2.5.6'

from fastai import *
from fastai.tabular.all import *

data = (TabularList.from_df(df, 
                            cat_names=cat_features,
                            cont_names=num_features, 
                            procs=preprocessing)
                   .split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42)
                   .label_from_df(cols=DEP_VAR)
                   .databunch())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [31], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data = (TabularList.from_df(df, 
      2                             cat_names=cat_features,
      3                             cont_names=num_features, 
      4                             procs=preprocessing)
      5                    .split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42)
      6                    .label_from_df(cols=DEP_VAR)
      7                    .databunch())

NameError: name 'TabularList' is not defined
```

I check the file of all.py, it is almost empty except the below import, so I think fastai might not be installed correctly? I am using

conda install -c fastai fastai

and

from fastai import *

works

```
from ..basics import *
from ..callback.all import *
from .core import *
from .data import *
from .model import *
from .learner import *
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a deprecated fastai library. Use the latest version going forward:[fastai documentation](https://docs.fast.ai/)